# Check password and create user manually with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, passwords, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle in my application. I would like to do two things via HTTP services:

1. Check password. The service could look like this (the password wouldn't be encrypted):

   ```
   public function checkPasswordValidity($userId, $password) {
       $user = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('MyCompany\UserBundle\Entity\User')
           ->find($userId);

       if (specialFunction($user , $password))
           echo 'Valid Password';
       else
           echo 'Invalid Password';
   }
   ```
2. Create a new user via another HTTP service. The parameters would be the username and the password.

Answer (score 63):

1. Check password:

   ```
   $encoder_service = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
   $encoder = $encoder_service->getEncoder($user);
   $encoded_pass = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());

   //then compare    $user->getPassword() and $encoded_pass
   ```
2. Create a new user:

   ```
   $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
   $user = $userManager->createUser();
   $user->setUsername($login);
   $user->setPlainPassword($pass);
   ...
   $userManager->updateUser($user);
   ```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  The encoded password and password in the database were different.

Comment: Do you work with  the same encoder ?, you should check your config.yml

Comment: Full documentation about FOS' UserManager can be found at http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html

Answer (score 6):

For me works:

```
$encoder_service = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$encoder = $encoder_service->getEncoder($user);
if ($encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password, $user->getSalt()) {}
```

I did not test second question, but I think it is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9841163/941493) already.

Answer (score 1):

### Manually add new user :

Login to ***phpmyadmin*** , access ***fos_user_user*** table , click insert > fill fields , username , email,roles etc.

Generate salt and password using this php script:

```
<?php 

$salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);

echo "Salt used: " . $salt ."<br/>";

echo "<br/>";

$password = 'adminpasswordhere';
$salted = $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
$digest = hash('sha512', $salted, true);

for ($i=1; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $digest = hash('sha512', $digest.$salted, true);
}

$encodedPassword = base64_encode($digest);

echo "Password used: " . $password ."<br/>";

echo "<br/>";

echo "Encrypted Password: " . $encodedPassword ."<br/>";


?>
```

### Enjoy !